# MATLAB - Check matrix to see if two consecutive numbers = 0

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

I have a matrix being created in MATLAB but need to check if any two consecutive numbers (by row) = 0 and if it does output with a yes or no without showing the answers. Ive put my code below my final loop is returning errors and im not too sure how to go about this.

```
    %%Input positive integer
n=input('Give a positive integer greater than 1: ');
    %%Error for below 1
if n<=1
error('The value given is less than or equal to 1')
end
    %%loop for vector v
for i=1:n
    v(i)=2^i*3;
end
    %display vector
v

A=randi([-5,5],n,n);

A

x = 1;
consecutive = false;
for i = 1:25
  if  (A(x) + A(x+1) = 0);
      consecutive = true;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

There's *a lot* wrong with the code of your final loop:

- You set `x` to 1 and use it as an index into `A`, but never change it from 1.
- As [Amit points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47171182/52738), you are using `=` (used for assignment) when you should be using `==` (the [equality operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html)).
- As [Gondrian points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47171767/52738), you are testing if a *sum* is equal to zero, but from your description it sounds like you should be testing if each value is zero.
- Your loop iterates 25 times (`i = 1:25`), but it's not clear why, since your matrix `A` is of size `n`-by-`n`.

Instead of using a for loop, it's possible to do this with [indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) instead. Since you are checking for consecutive zeroes *by row*, this is what it would look like:

```
zeroPairs = (A(:, 1:(n-1)) == 0) & (A(:, 2:n) == 0);
consecutive = any(zeroPairs(:));
```

The term `A(:, 1:(n-1))` gets all of the "left" values in each pairwise comparison and the term `A(:, 2:n)` gets all of the "right" value. These are compared to 0, then [combined](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html). This creates an `n`-by-`(n-1)` matrix `zeroPairs` where a value of `true` indicates where a pair of consecutive zeroes occurs. This matrix is [reshaped into a column vector](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) and [`any`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) is used to check if a value of `true` is present anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your `if` block as follows.

```
  if  (A(x) + A(x+1) == 0);
      consecutive = true;
  end
```

Notice the `==` instead of just `=`. The first one is for comparison and the second one is for assignment. This will get rid of the error that you are currently getting. There may be other issues in the algorithm of your code but I did not examine or try to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

btw:

> 'if any two consecutive numbers (by row) = 0'

If I understand you right, you should try 'if  A(x) == 0 && A(x+1) == 0';
because '(A(x) + A(x+1) == 0)' would be true for -5 and 5, as it equals to 0. But -5 and 5 are not two consecutive zeros.

(or even look at the 'diff' function. It will return a 0 if two following numbers are the same)

Answer (score 0):

To show a vectorized, more Matlab-like approach:

```
v = 0; % sought value
C = 2; % desired number of consecutive values in a row
consecutive = nnz(conv2(double(A==v), ones(1,C))==C)>0;
```

This compares each entry of `A` with the value `v`, and then applies 2D convolution with a row vector of `C` ones. Any `C` horizontally-consecutive entries of `A` with value `v` will produce an entry equal to `C` in the convolution result. So we check if the number of such entries is positive.